# No internal speaker sound (i.e. without headphones) coming from my motherboard

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, system-sounds

Without headphones there is no sound coming from a used Asus pc I bought. Even a console beep cannot be heard without headphones. I have tried updating sound drivers, installing realtek audio driver, have checked audio controller in BIOS (it's enabled) but nothing's helped.

Besides that when I check sound settings, it says '**Speakers (High definition Audio device) not plugged in**'. What does it mean? Do I have to connect speakers with it? Mostly computers have sound coming from their motherboards even if speakers are not attached. How to get that internal speaker working?

Thanks

Comment: Most motherboards these days don't even have a system beeper, just the headers to add your own. Speakers are a completely different thing; though your probable cause is the connections are loose - as headphones work, the audio structure is there, just either not connected, or the headphone socket is not releasing correctly when unplugged.. Open the machine & trace the cabling.

Comment: In summary, *Do I have to connect speakers with it?* Yes, of course.